# How to create a Decision Tree?

Tags: decision-tree

So I have this problem with 12 customers purchasing 5 different items. 0 meaning they did not buy that product and 1 means they did purchase that item.

So I'm having trouble on how to start with this...

[image: Customer-Items Table Graph]

Comment: Could help you along: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_table

Comment: What are you trying to decide?

Comment: The question says to create a decision tree. That's all...

Comment: What are you trying to predict?  Are you trying to build a 'decision tree' or, as Vipar has outlined, use a 'Decision Table' for some purpose?